# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AND' in query

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

When I will click checkboxlist2 item without selecting checkboxlist1 item, then button search getting an error. I think checkboxlist2 coding is wrong, Please follow below code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!this.IsPostBack)
    {
        this.BindGrid();
    }

}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    this.BindGrid();
}

private void BindGrid()
{
    string conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    string query = "SELECT * FROM Table_RegistrationInfo WHERE true";
    string condition = string.Empty;
    foreach (ListItem item in CheckBoxList1.Items)
    {
        condition += item.Selected ? string.Format("'{0}',", item.Value) : "";
    }
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(condition))
    {
        condition = string.Format(" AND Nationality in ({0})", condition.Substring(0, condition.Length - 1));
    }
    string condition2 = string.Empty;
    foreach (ListItem item in CheckBoxList2.Items)
    {
        condition2 += item.Selected ? string.Format("'{0}',", item.Value) : "";
    }
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(condition2))
    {
        //condition = string.Format(" where Nationality in ({0})", condition.Substring(0, condition.Length - 1));
        condition2 = string.Format(" AND GivenName in ({0})", condition2.Substring(0, condition2.Length - 1));
    }
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query + condition + condition2); using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
    {
        using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
        {
            cmd.Connection = con; sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
            using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
            {
                sda.Fill(ds);
                GridView2.DataSource = ds;
                GridView2.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }


}
protected void Select_Nationality(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.BindGrid();
}
protected void Select_GivenName(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach(ListItem item in CheckBoxList1.Items)
    {
        if(item.Selected == true)
        {
            this.BindGrid();
        }
    }
}
```

I have to implement 8 checkbox lists for filtering into gridview. If any other easy techniques to implement and I have to use filtered from 3 tables.

Comment: What is your final query exactly? Just before you execute it? Looks like `!string.IsNullOrEmpty(condition)` returns `false` and you try to add `AND...` part without `WHERE`.

Comment: What is the results of `condition2.Substring(0, condition2.Length - 1)`??

Comment: I am not sure if you have made it mandatory that first condition cannot be null and condition2 cannot be given with out first condition. If that is the case you need to have condition2 might add AND in the query and FIrst condition will be empty.

Comment: No, first query is for checkboxlist1 like "where Nationality in ({0})"  and checkboxlist2 like " AND GivenName in ({0})" . later i am doing to add all SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query + condition + condition2);. The problem is when i will select checkboxlist2 item and click search button then only getting error, because only AND GivenName in ({0})"  query is executing. @SonerGönül

Comment: Ya. you are correct. Can you send me your answer. @MohitShrivastava

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `condition` is null or empty, your query becomes:

```
SELECT ... FROM ... AND ...
```

which is incorrect.

You can fix it by make your "base" query like this:

```
SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE 1=1
```

and then append pieces like `AND ...` to it. Your query then becomes (when only `condition` is valid:

```
SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE 1=1 AND condition
```

which is equivalent to

```
SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE condition
```

In your case, change this:

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM Table_RegistrationInfo";
```

into

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM Table_RegistrationInfo WHERE 1=1 ";
```

and change this:

```
condition = string.Format(" where Nationality in ({0})", condition.Substring(0, condition.Length - 1));
```

into

```
condition = string.Format(" AND Nationality in ({0})", condition.Substring(0, condition.Length - 1));
```

Comment: still i am confused, can you update according to above code. @Bart

Comment: I updated my answer.

Comment: An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near '1'.

Comment: Getting error. @Bart

Comment: Change `1` into `true`, what SQL server are you using?

Comment: sql server 2008, why we are using 1 after where?. @Bart Friederichs

Comment: @user3745321 in MySQL for example, `1` is equivalent to `true` (apperently in SQL Server it isn't). In Boolean logic, `true AND x` equals `x`. This way, you can concatenate conditions, without the need for weird parsing, just append ` AND [somecondition]`.

Comment: still getting confuse, can you update once again answer. @ Bart Friederichs

Comment: I just updated it, with a little more explanation. I also advise you to read up on SQL and Boolean logic.

Comment: An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'true'. Getting like this error. @Bart

Comment: What is your complete resulting query?

Comment: Check i had update above my question code according you. @Bart

Comment: SQL server 2008 needs a real condition, not just a boolean value. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much, you are great and saved my life. Thank you once again.

Comment: i need one suggestion can we implement 8 checkbox lists for filtering into gridview in this same way.@Bart

Comment: Yes, you can append as many `AND [condition]` as you want.

Comment: Ok thank you your will be helpful to all. @Bart

Answer (score 0):

modify your code.

```
    private void BindGrid()
    {
        string conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        string query = "SELECT * FROM Table_RegistrationInfo";
        string condition = string.Empty;
        foreach(ListItem item in CheckBoxList1.Items)
        {
            condition += item.Selected ? string.Format("'{0}',", item.Value) : "";
        }
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(condition))
        {
            condition = string.Format(" where Nationality in ({0})", condition.Substring(0, condition.Length - 1));
        }
        string condition2 = string.Empty;
        foreach(ListItem item in CheckBoxList2.Items)
        {
            condition2 += item.Selected ? string.Format("'{0}',", item.Value) : "";
        }
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(condition2))
        {
         if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(condition))
            {
            condition+=" And ";
            }
       else {
            Condition +=" Where "
            }


  //condition = string.Format(" where Nationality in ({0})", condition.Substring(0, condition.Length - 1));
            condition2 = string.Format(" GivenName in ({0})", condition2.Substring(0, condition2.Length - 1));
        }
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query + condition + condition2);
        using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
        {
            using(SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;
                sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                using(DataSet ds = new DataSet())
                {
                    sda.Fill(ds);
                    GridView2.DataSource = ds;
                    GridView2.DataBind();
                }
            }
        }

    }
```